# Format strings to make 'table' in Python 3

Tags: python, formatting, tabular

Right now I'm using `print()`, calling the variables I want that are stored in a tuple and then formatting them using: `print(format(x,"<10s")+ format(y,"<40s")...)` but this gives me output that isn't aligned in a column form. How do I make it so that each row's element is aligned?

So, my code is for storing student details. First, it takes a string and returns a tuple, with constituent parts like: (name,surname,student ID, year).
It reads these details from a long text file on student details, and then it parses them through a tuplelayout function (the bit which will format the tuple) and is meant to tabulate the results.
So, the argument for the tuplelayout function is a tuple, of the form:
`surname | name | reg number | course | year`

Answer (score 6):

If you are unpacking tuples just use a single `str.format` and justify the output as required  using [format-specification-mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
l = [(10,1000),(200,20000)]

for x,y in l:
    print("{:<3} {:<6}".format(x,y))

10  1000  
200 20000
```

Comment: This can't fit into my code, because you're using a list of tuples. If you try it on just one tuple, then you get an error: "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack", and I don't know how to fix that. Any help?

Comment: well you cannot have x and y variables if you only have a single element, you can check if your tuple has one or two items, what are x and y supposed to be in your own code?

Comment: My code also works on a single tuple but I don't see how a single  tuple will form a table or why would need to justify single elements

Comment: So, my code is for storing student details.
First, it takes a string and returns a tuple, with constituent parts like: (name,surname,student ID, year). 
It reads these details from a long text file on student details, and then it parses them through a tuplelayout function (the bit which will format the tuple) and is meant to tabulate the results.

So, the argument for the tuplelayout function is a tuple, of the form:  
surname | name | reg number | course | year  

Can I simply

Comment: Can I simply use `print("{:<10} {:<22}{:<7}{:<5}{:<5}".format(tple))`?

Answer (score 0):

My shell has the font settings changed so the alignment was off. Back to font: `"Courier"` and everything is working fine.
Sorry.